# Paper data backup on Linux?

Tags: backup, printing

Does there exist a tool like [Paperback](http://ollydbg.de/Paperbak/) for Linux?

> PaperBack is a free application that allows you to back up your precious files on the ordinary paper in the form of the oversized bitmaps. If you have a good laser printer with the 600 dpi resolution, you can save up to 500,000 bytes of uncompressed data on the single A4/Letter sheet. Integrated packer allows for much better data density - up to 3,000,000+ (three megabytes) of C code per page.

That is, something that can represent more data than e.g. QR codes, and can be printed on paper?

Comment: Someone started a fork - https://github.com/timwaters/paperback.

Comment: These are alts that show up for Paperback - https://alternativeto.net/software/paperback-by-olly/.

Comment: At this point I'm thinking this Q should be moved to softwarerec instead of U&L.

Comment: "paperback-cli: Cross-OS port for OlyDbg's Paperbak program." and other paper data storage projects are listed at https://github.com/za3k/qr-backup/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#what-other-paper-backup-projects-exist